# Returning items from dataContext that have the matched ID

Tags: c#, .net-core, ienumerable

I'm trying to implement this method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetListOfProductsAsync(List<int> ids)
{
    var products = await this.GetAllProductsAsync();
    return products.Where(pr => ids.Contains(pr.Id));
}
```

I want to return a list of products where the ids match.

So for example, if I pass in `[1,3,5]`, the method should return the products with ids 1, 3 and 5. However its not working properly.

When I execute it with only 1 id, it works fine, however when I pass in multiple ids, it fails with this error in Swagger:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-f6d957f9875ec28236d9c5abe26500d3-00b20e33f715d7c0-00",
  "errors": {
    "ids": [
      "The value '4,2' is not valid."
    ]
  }
}
```

[image: this is how i put my array in swagger]

[image: Network tab]

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Based on the error it looks like you are making the request with a string ("4,2") instead of an array ([4, 2]). Can you show the request details?

Comment: @Crowcoder how tho in my controller i have it in such format [FromQuery] List<int> ids, and in swagger it takes a list

Comment: @PeterCsala its not working as it should it should return me all the products that have those specific ids, and i dont understand whats wrong

Comment: Using the network tab of the browser dev tools, can you show the Request details when you submit that?

Comment: @Crowcoder your right it is showing as ids = ["1,2"], but how tho? i have it specified as an integer why is it turning into a string?

Comment: I guess that is just the way Swagger is implemented. If you are passing that in the query string then you either have to take the data as a string and split it on commas or pass multiple parameters with the same name like: `...?ids=1&ids=2&ids=4`